# How to find a User ID from a Username in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a json file (localJSON.json) with Discord usernames (i.e. JohnDoe#1234) and need to get the User IDs from these usernames in order to have a role added. Every place I have looked online has resulted with either an 'undefined' or 'null' value for rMember. Verified that the code to add a role works when given a User ID as a string, but can't find how to get a User ID from a username. 
How do I get a user's ID from their Username using Discord.js?

```
localJSON.json
[
  {
    "discordName": "JohnDoe#1234"
  },
  {
    "discordName": "MarySue#5678"
  }
]
```

```
function addRole(discordUsername, gameName, message){
  var roleName = "";
  //Switch statement to assign roleName to a valid guild role based on argument

  var userID = discordUsername.id; //Pseudo code, Need to accomplish this

  var rMember = message.guild.members.get(userID); //Needs UserID as string
  var gRole = message.guild.roles.find((role) => role.name == roleName); 
  if (!rMember) { //if member not in server
    message.channel.send(rMember + " is not in the server!");
  } else { //assign role
    rMember.addRole(gRole);
  }
}

async run(message, args){
  ...
  for (var i = 0; i < localJSON.length; i++) {
     var currentEntry = localJSON[i];
     var currrentUserName = currentEntry.discordName;
     addRole(currrentUserName, args, message); //addRole(discordUsername, gameName, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Storing users using their usernames and tags is a bad idea, you need to store users using their IDs so that you don't have to deal with issues like these.

Comment: Users put their username in a form when they sign up on a website, which is where I get the JSON from. All I have are the usernames, no IDs.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to do

```js
client.users.cache.find(u => u.tag === 'Someone#1234').id
```

Discord.js v12 uses `.cache` now, so you have to run find on the cache, and v12 also removes `Collection#find(key, value)` in favor of `Collection#find(data => data.key === value)`.

Comment: `client.users` is `null`, with an array length of 0.

`_array: null, _keyArray: null, [[Entries]]: Array(0), size: 0`

Comment: @Conman1161 That's not good, `client.users` should never be null, could you show your entire code for more context?

Comment: I have everything relevant to my issue in the original post. Using VS Code Insider for debugging and a breakpoint showed client.users to be empty.
`const Discord = require("discord.js");`
`const client = new Discord.Client();`
`function addRole(discordUsername, gameName, message) {`
`var userID = client.users.cache.find((u) => u.tag === discordUsername).id;`
`console.log(userID);`

Comment: Weird, I really don't know then

Comment: This will only return users which have been cached before.