# How to tag player and recieve their discord id in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I have been trying to figure out how to tag people and then receive their user id. I attempted to make a code for that but the problem is it is receiving the user-id twice in a particular pattern. For example:

My code:
FirstUser - 1234566
Second user- 1234576
1234576
Third user - 1234586
1234586
1234586

I want the code to run like this:

First User - 1234566
Second User - 1234576
Third User - 1234586

Here is my code below:
(The "joined" is my array of people that have joined the game. This works perfectly)

```
client.on('message', function(playerFind) {
    const playerID = playerFind.content;
    if (playerFind.author.bot) return;
    let mention = playerFind.mentions.users.first();
    if((playerID.startsWith('!find id ')) && (mention) && (joined.length > 0)){
        for(var i = 0; i < joined.length; i++){
            if(mention.id === user[joined[i]].getID()) {
                playerFind.channel.send(mention.id);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find a User ID from a Username in Discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61284468/how-to-find-a-user-id-from-a-username-in-discord-js)

Comment: No, the link you gave me focuses on something else. I want to get user id in from each element of an array but the program I did it repeats it in a pattern

Answer (score 0):

I've not used discord.js since mid 2019, but back then it would've been

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
var command = message.content.split(" ")[0];
if(!command.startsWith(prefix)) return;

if(command === "getid") {
  message.channel.send(message.content.mentions.users.first().id)
}

});
```

I believe, as I said, it's been a while.

Comment: The getting id works, its just that I'm trying to print each User object in the array, but after the 0th element, it is printing more than once. Ex: 0th element: 123456 1st element: 123455 123455 and so on...