# Add/Remove user role given username (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a function for adding and removing a role from a user given the username (not user ID).

So far I have code that works with user ID. My question is how can I modify this code to work given the username?

```
const addDiscord = async (discord_username) => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('<guild-id>');   // copy the id of the server your bot is in and paste it in place of guild-ID.
    const role = guild.roles.cache.get('<role-id>');  // here we are getting the role object using the id of that role.
    const member = await guild.members.fetch('user-id'); // here we are getting the member object using the id of that member. This is the member we will add the role to.
    await member.roles.add(role);   // here we just added the role to the member we got.
}
```

Here is my function that will handle checking for new user to add/remove

```
const checkNew = async () => {
    if(toUpdate.length > 0) { // Check if there are any new users to update
        toUpdate.forEach(element => {
            addDiscord(element.new)
            // Remove element.old from Discord role
            // Add element.new to Discord role
        })
        toUpdate = []
    }
}
```

And here I am connecting to bot and calling the checkNew() function every 10 seconds

```
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');

    setInterval(checkNew, 10000)
});
```

**Update:**
I tried using client.users.cache.find() but it returns undefined

```
const addDiscord = async (discord_username) => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('<guild-id>');   // copy the id of the server your bot is in and paste it in place of guild-ID.
    const role = guild.roles.cache.get('<role-id>');  // here we are getting the role object using the id of that role.
    console.log(discord_username)
    const id = client.users.cache.find(u => u.tag === discord_username)
    console.log(id)
}
```

**Update 2:** Attempted to implement the code from Miqhtie's answer

```
const addDiscord = async (discord_username) => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('<server-id>');   // copy the id of the server your bot is in and paste it in place of guild-ID.
    const role = guild.roles.cache.get('<role-id>');  // here we are getting the role object using the id of that role.
    const members = await guild.members.fetch()
    const member = members.find((m) => m.username === '<discord-username>')
    console.log(member)
}
```

Error:

```
const member = members.find((m) => m.username === '<discord-username>')
                           ^
TypeError: members.find is not a function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find a User ID from a Username in Discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61284468/how-to-find-a-user-id-from-a-username-in-discord-js)

Comment: @FelixGerberding thank you for the quick response. I tried the client.users.cache.find() method but ran into some trouble. Updated my question with the code

Comment: Tested it just now, worked perfectly fine. Are you trying to search by tag (test#1234) or the nickname that can be set per server?

Comment: Trying to search by tag. I also tried logging the client.users.cache but it returns a collection of 1, which only has the discord bot user object inside.

Comment: Are you sure the intents are correct?

Comment: @FelixGerberding apologies for my ignorance. I likely did not set the intents correctly. I have enabled "Server Members Intent" in the developer dashboard. Perhaps there are some other required intents I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific method to fetch a GuildMember by username so what you would have to do is fetch all the members from a guild
`<guild>.members.fetch()`
and then filter it for a member whos username property is equal to the username you want.

An example implementation of this would be

```js
const username = "Super Cool Username";
const members = await guild.members.fetch();
const member = members.find((m) => m.username === username);
member.roles.cache.add(role);
```

Comment: Thank you. I attempted to implement this code, but I run into an error with members.find(). I posted the code at the bottom of my question along with the error

Comment: You are doing guild.fetch() instead of guild.members.fetch()

Comment: Oops. Thanks, I updated it with guild.members.fetch() . I try logging both members and member, but nothing seems to be logging to the console. I assumed it may just take a while to fetch all the members, but after 5 mins nothing still. Logging a string before fetch() appears in the console, but logging a string after fetch() does not appear.

Comment: I believe it may be an issue with how I am using async/await

Comment: You probably do not have the server members intent enabled. You must do this on your applications dashboard in the bot section on discords website

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it by adding intents.

Comment: GuildMembers do not have usernames, Users do. You'll need to use `m.user.username == ...`